# Query to print triangle star(asterisk) for given N value in SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am developing an Query in SQL or PL/SQL as the below structured. I have tried the following query

```
SELECT     RPAD ('* ', LEVEL*2, '* ')
 FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 
UNION all
SELECT   RPAD ('* ', LEVEL*2, '* ')
 FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

But the Output i am getting is in this form.

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

**But the output format i needed is**

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

Can anyone help me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT     RPAD ('* ', LEVEL*2, '* ')
FROM       DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 
UNION all
SELECT   RPAD ('* ', (5-LEVEL)*2, '* ')
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right one.

```
SELECT     RPAD (' ', LEVEL*2, ' ')
FROM       DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 
UNION all
SELECT   RPAD (' ', (5-LEVEL)*2, ' ')
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5-1;
```

Hope it helps you out..!!